# How to access iframe into parent window from iframe itself?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a top document like this (top and iframes are same origin) :

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <iframe class="loaded" src="https://www.example.com/article/645114"/>
    <iframe class="loaded" src="https://www.example.com/article/184789"/>
    <iframe class="loaded" src="https://www.example.com/article/4325"/>
    <iframe class="loaded" src="https://www.example.com/article/32586"/>
    </body>
    </html>
```

If a script runs in `https://www.example.com/article/4325` I would like to know :

`"This is running from frame 3"`

The same script running in `https://www.example.com/article/645114` would return :

`"This is running from frame 1"`

How shoud I do ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in the script running in the iframe:

```
var loadeds = top.document.querySelectorAll('.loaded');
for(var i = 0; i < loadeds.length; i++){
    var src = loadeds[i].getAttribute('src'),
        this_url = document.URL;

    if(src === this_url){

        console.log('This is running from frame ' + (i + 1) + ' with the src attribute as ' + this_url);

        // Alternatively you could use.
        // alert('This is running from frame ' + (i + 1) + ' with the src attribute as ' + this_url);
    }
}
```

Didn't get to try it, but if you run this script in an iframe with your HTML structure above, you should get a console message telling you which frame the script is running in.

Comment: Works perfectly. Helps a lot. Thank you!